# After successfull sign up, call the sign in method of devise and pass required paramters to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my application I have used devise for registration purpose and it is working fine.

I have written another sign up method (I have to kept both the sign up methods) and able to register the user. Here is my code

new.html.haml

```
%h1 User Registration

= form_tag participant_user_registrations_path do
  = label_tag :full_name
  = text_field_tag :full_name

  = label_tag :address
  = text_area_tag :address, "", :rows => 5, :cols => 20

  = label_tag :mobile_number
  = text_field_tag :mobile_number

  = label_tag :email
  = text_field_tag :email

  = label_tag :slogan
  = text_area_tag :slogan, "", :rows => 5, :cols => 20

  = label_tag :password
  = password_field_tag :password

  = label_tag :activation_code
  = text_field_tag :activation_code

  = submit_tag "Sign Up", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

In my system username is auto-generated (we have a fixed format for it like full_name + mobile_no)

My user registration method

```
def another_registration
  @user = User.new(:client_id => 122,
                   :full_name => params["full_name"], 
                   :mobile_number => params["mobile_number"],
                   :address => params["address"],
                   :email => params["email"],
                   :participant_id => params["mobile_number"],
                   :status => "active",
                   :slogan => params["slogan"],
                   :password => params["password"])  
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "User is saved"
  else
    flash[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages.first #if @user.errors.any?
  end
  redirect_to :action => "new"
end
```

After successfully sign up I have to login the user account.

I have to use existing devise sign in functionality, so how can I call the devise sign in method and how to pass parameters to it.

Currently I am using username and password for the sign in.

Comment: I think that you should use `stong parameters` in your controller action:
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html


For the sign in, Devise has an action called `sign_in()` 
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut

Comment: I am using rails 3.2.11

Comment: Oh, didn't see the tag. But the devise helper should work?